# jsoup get output storage?

Tags: jsoup

I am running windows with kaspersky anti virus.

I have performed a

```
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

link some how happened to be a viruswebsite.
when ever I run this command my Anti-virus window will pop-up and tell "blocked website as there is a trojan".

My question is when we do get? where is the website physically stored? (document) (or) is it inmememory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Document` is stored in memory. But i think the alert here is caused when you "download" the website via `get()`. Kaspersky will scan your incoming traffic and if there's a virus / trojan / ... block it.

Comment: so if I dont have Anti-virus will it be a problem? Because it is in memory and is deleted when I exit my program I was thinking It should be ok with out Antu-virus but want to confirm

Comment: i dont recommend this, but if you are 100 % shure its no trojan ... nevertheless its a good idea to check with a 2nd antivirus program, possible its a false positive.